component refresh while using Link component on next js
Is there a way with next.js v14.1.4 to navigate from /projects/123 to /projects/124 shallowly?
Here's my file structure:
projects
[id]
page.tsx
I have this code in my child component
<Link
    href={`projects/${activeProject.id}`}
   >
     {activeProject.name}
</Link>

What I need to achieve - I have a sidebar with projects list on the left of the page and selected projects on the right. So when clicking a projects title in sidebar I show it on the right and I also need to update the url, without refreshing the page.
What I need to achieve - I have a sidebar with projects list on the left of the page and selected projects on the right. So when clicking a projects title in sidebar I show it on the right and I also need to update the url, without refreshing the page.

1. From where are you importing <Link> component ? 2. Add the full code for sidebar component. 3. Sidebar is client-side or server-side ? Update question & Remove duplicate part from it.
